# How can I generate a random int using the "crypto/rand" package?

Tags: go

Say I would like to generate a secure random int between 0 and 27 using:

```
func Int(rand io.Reader, max *big.Int) (n *big.Int, err error)
```

in the `"crypto/rand"` package.

How would I do that?

I do not really understand how this works, why does it not return one of the built in Go ints instead of pointer to some big.Int type?

EDIT:

Would this be considered secure enough for tokens?

```
func getToken(length int) string {
    token := ""
    codeAlphabet := "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    codeAlphabet += "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    codeAlphabet += "0123456789"

    for i := 0; i < length; i++ {
        token += string(codeAlphabet[cryptoRandSecure(int64(len(codeAlphabet)))])
    }
    return token
}

func cryptoRandSecure(max int64) int64 {
    nBig, err := rand.Int(rand.Reader, big.NewInt(max))
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
    return nBig.Int64()
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(getToken(32))
}
```

This would output something like this:

```
qZDbuPwNQGrgVmZCU9A7FUWbp8eIfn0Z

EwZVoQ5D5SEfdhiRsDfH6dU6tAovILCZ

cOqzODVP0GwbiNBwtmqLA78rFgV9d3VT
```

Comment: Do you really need a "cryptographically secure pseudorandom number" ? (from the doc https://godoc.org/crypto/rand) If you do not, you can use https://godoc.org/math/rand

Comment: I need it to generate secure tokens. Like the one I showed above. I would like it if it could include all characters from the alphabet including digits.

Comment: Just saw your edit. An alternate way could be to generate a really big random int (like between 0 and the max int64) and to encode it in hexadecimal or base32. I'll add it to my answer

Comment: Normally if someone needs a cryptographically strong random number she won't need a range of [0,27] (which is 5 bit) but something **much** larger, more like 2048 bits which just does not fit into an int64. So a big.int is returned. Maybe you should generate a long bit sequence and simply base32 encode it?

Comment: "Cryptographically secure PRNG" and "5 bits" does not go together. At a minimum a token (say, for CSRF or session IDs) should be 256 bits. I would rethink your approach.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you're generating secure tokens for session IDs, OAuth Bearer tokens, CSRF or similar: you want to generate a token of (ideally) 256 bits (32 bytes) or no less than 192 bits (24 bytes).

A token with values between (0-27) can be brute-forced in less than a second and could not be considered secure.

e.g.

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/rand"
    "encoding/base64"
)

// GenerateRandomBytes returns securely generated random bytes.
// It will return an error if the system's secure random
// number generator fails to function correctly, in which
// case the caller should not continue.
func GenerateRandomBytes(n int) ([]byte, error) {
    b := make([]byte, n)
    _, err := rand.Read(b)
    // Note that err == nil only if we read len(b) bytes.
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return b, nil
}

// GenerateRandomString returns a URL-safe, base64 encoded
// securely generated random string.
func GenerateRandomString(s int) (string, error) {
    b, err := GenerateRandomBytes(s)
    return base64.URLEncoding.EncodeToString(b), err
}

func main() {
    // Example: this will give us a 44 byte, base64 encoded output
    token, err := GenerateRandomString(32)
    if err != nil {
        // Serve an appropriately vague error to the
        // user, but log the details internally.
    }
}
```

The base64 output is safe for headers, HTTP forms, JSON bodies, etc.

If you need an integer it may help to explain your use-case, as it would be odd for a system to require tokens as ints.

Comment: Hi elithrar, I edited my posts. I wanted to use it to create tokens for different things such as password resets and for keys to be dealt out to people for registration for a closed website and so on.

Comment: @Aiden In that case you don't need random integers. A sufficiently random string (base64, hex, whatever) would be more than fine. My snippet above uses `base64.URLEncoding` to generate strings you can use in a URL - e.g. `yourdomain.com/resetpassword?token=YW55m5hbCIGNhcm5hbCBwbGVhc3U=` would cover that use-case. As a tip: make sure you strictly enforce a single-use and expiry date on the tokens in your backend (SQL, Redis, etc.) as  there are lots of sharp edges around re-using password reset tokens that don't expire "correctly".

Answer (score 50):

Here is some working code :

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "crypto/rand"
    "math/big"
)

func main() {
    nBig, err := rand.Int(rand.Reader, big.NewInt(27))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    n := nBig.Int64()
    fmt.Printf("Here is a random %T in [0,27) : %d\n", n, n)
}
```

---

But to generate a random token, I'd do something like this :

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/rand"
    "encoding/base32"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    token := getToken(10)
    fmt.Println("Here is a random token : ", token)
}

func getToken(length int) string {
    randomBytes := make([]byte, 32)
    _, err := rand.Read(randomBytes)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return base32.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(randomBytes)[:length]
}
```

Comment: Also see https://www.socketloop.com/tutorials/golang-how-to-generate-random-string (using base64, so more than just the alphabet and numbers https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)

Comment: I'd suggest at least 24 (if not 32) bytes for any kind of tokens.

Comment: the `getToken` function, as currently written, only works if `length` is <= 56. Changing the first line in the function to `randomBytes := make([]byte, length)` will work for any value of `length`. Under the covers it will create a longer byte slice than needed but not that much more. The resulting random string will always be `length` long.

Answer (score 2):

If you only need a small number (i.e. [0, 255]), you could just read a byte out of the package's `Reader`:

```
b := []byte{0}
if _, err := rand.Reader.Read(b); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
n := b[0]
fmt.Println(n)
```

Playground: http://play.golang.org/p/4VO52LiEVh (the example won't work there, I don't know if it's working as intended or it's a playground bug).

Comment: About the playground, there is this issue which was marked as fixed but actually isn't : https://github.com/golang/go/issues/5096 . I left a comment there