# How to pick a random number every time from a list

Tags: go, random, chunks

The goal: pick a random number from a list every time a chunk is generated

Python code example to make it more clear.

I have this list:

```
listbytes = [87, 88, 89, 90]
```

And this function which splits the data:

```
def chunks(lst, n):
"Yield successive chunks from lst, where n is a list of possible sizes"
    i = 0
    while i < len(lst):
        k = min(random.choice(n), len(lst) - i)
        yield lst[i:i + k]
        i += k
```

And I call it this way:

```
for chunk in chunks(d, listbytes):
    ......
```

Every chunk created has a random size from 87 to 90, so:
1 chunk may have the size of 87, the next one may have the size of 90, and so on..

I have a similar function in Go which splits the data:

```
func split(buf []byte, lim int) [][]byte {
    var chunk []byte
    chunks := make([][]byte, 0, len(buf)/lim+1)
    for len(buf) >= lim {
        chunk, buf = buf[:lim], buf[lim:]
        chunks = append(chunks, chunk)
    }
    if len(buf) > 0 {
        chunks = append(chunks, buf[:len(buf)])
    }
    return chunks
}
```

The difference between this and the one in python is that the data is chunked using a fixed number. Example:

```
for _, chunk := range split(buf[:n], 100) {
    .......
```

This will chunk the data with a fixed size of 100, so every chunk has a size of 100, while with python is a random size from 87 to 90.

The desired output is the same thing: the chunks should have a random size everytime.

How can I achieve the same goal but in go?

Comment: can you explain clearly what is your question, input and desired output? do you need to get random element from `listbytes = [87, 88, 89, 90]` ?

Comment: An equivalent way of what is shown in python, yes. Get a random element from a list of numbers, which will be used to generate chunks. Everytime the chunks is generated should have a different size based on the picked element

Comment: use rand.Intn(n) with n equal to len(listbytes)-1 to generate a random index (let say i) and listbytes[i] to pick that from slice. Beware though that this sequence is deterministic, if you plan to use this to generate tokens or a simillar usecase, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32349807/how-can-i-generate-a-random-int-using-the-crypto-rand-package/32350135 should help you with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the Go version of your Python program (with a little main to run it):

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "math/rand"
  "time"
)

// split breaks buf into a slice of slices whose lengths
// are randomly chosen from sizes, except for the last slice.
// The last slice's length is less than or equal to a size that 
// was chosen from sizes, but may be larger than some other size
// found in sizes.
func split(r *rand.Rand, buf []byte, sizes []int) [][]byte {
    var chunk []byte
    chunks := make([][]byte, 0)
    for len(buf) > 0 {
        sz := sizes[r.Intn(len(sizes))]
        if sz > len(buf) {
           sz = len(buf)
        } 
        chunk, buf = buf[:sz], buf[sz:]
        chunks = append(chunks, chunk)
    }
    return chunks
}

func main() {
    // Go's RNG is deterministic unless seeded with current time.
    s := int64(time.Now().Nanosecond())
    r := rand.New(rand.NewSource(s))

    sizes := []int{2,3,5,7}
    buf := []byte{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25}

    fmt.Printf("result=%v\n", split(r, buf, sizes))
}
```

Here's a Go playground link for the same (so you can easily see and run):
https://play.golang.org/p/U1vkPAKOQmI
(Note that the time is always the same at the Go playground, so that it always runs the same).

Answer (score 2):

A solution on top of `io.Reader`

main_test.go

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "math/rand"
    "strings"
    "time"
)

type rndReader struct {
    R       io.Reader
    Rnd     interface{ Intn(n int) int }
    buf     []byte
    lastErr error
}

func (r *rndReader) Read(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    if r.Rnd == nil {
        r.Rnd = rand.New(rand.NewSource(time.Now().Unix()))
    }
    if r.lastErr != nil && len(r.buf) < 1 {
        return 0, r.lastErr
    }
    // rather than a function argument (n), take len(p)
    j := len(p)
    if r.lastErr == nil {
        n, err = r.R.Read(p)            // read to p
        r.buf = append(r.buf, p[:n]...) // save the read
        r.lastErr = err
    }
    p = p[:0]                           // reset p, prepare it to receive the random chunk
    k := min(r.Rnd.Intn(j), len(r.buf)) // select a random k
    p = append(p, r.buf[:k]...)         // copy the desired portion from the internal buf to p
    copy(r.buf, r.buf[k:])              // re arrange the internal buffer
    r.buf = r.buf[:len(r.buf)-k]        // adjust its len.
    return len(p), nil
}

func min(n, k int) int {
    if n > k {
        return k
    }
    return n
}

func ExampleFromStrings() {
    in := strings.Repeat(`12345`, 4)
    s := strings.NewReader(in)

    r := rndReader{R: s, Rnd: rand.New(rand.NewSource(1))}
    out := make([]byte, 3)
    for {
        n, err := r.Read(out)
        if err != nil {
            break
        }
        fmt.Printf(`n=%v err=%v buf="%s"`+"\n", n, err, out[:n])
    }
    // Output:
    // n=2 err=<nil> buf="12"
    // n=0 err=<nil> buf=""
    // n=2 err=<nil> buf="34"
    // n=2 err=<nil> buf="51"
    // n=1 err=<nil> buf="2"
    // n=0 err=<nil> buf=""
    // n=1 err=<nil> buf="3"
    // n=2 err=<nil> buf="45"
    // n=1 err=<nil> buf="1"
    // n=0 err=<nil> buf=""
    // n=2 err=<nil> buf="23"
    // n=1 err=<nil> buf="4"
    // n=0 err=<nil> buf=""
    // n=2 err=<nil> buf="51"
    // n=1 err=<nil> buf="2"
    // n=2 err=<nil> buf="34"
    // n=0 err=<nil> buf=""
    // n=1 err=<nil> buf="5"
}

func ExampleFromBytes() {
    in := []byte(strings.Repeat(`12345`, 4))
    s := bytes.NewBuffer(in)

    r := rndReader{R: s, Rnd: rand.New(rand.NewSource(1))}
    out := make([]byte, 3)
    for {
        n, err := r.Read(out)
        if err != nil {
            break
        }
        fmt.Printf(`n=%v err=%v buf="%s"`+"\n", n, err, out[:n])
    }
    // Output:
    // n=2 err=<nil> buf="12"
    // n=0 err=<nil> buf=""
    // n=2 err=<nil> buf="34"
    // n=2 err=<nil> buf="51"
    // n=1 err=<nil> buf="2"
    // n=0 err=<nil> buf=""
    // n=1 err=<nil> buf="3"
    // n=2 err=<nil> buf="45"
    // n=1 err=<nil> buf="1"
    // n=0 err=<nil> buf=""
    // n=2 err=<nil> buf="23"
    // n=1 err=<nil> buf="4"
    // n=0 err=<nil> buf=""
    // n=2 err=<nil> buf="51"
    // n=1 err=<nil> buf="2"
    // n=2 err=<nil> buf="34"
    // n=0 err=<nil> buf=""
    // n=1 err=<nil> buf="5"
}

func main() {}
```