# Golang Strange random problems

Tags: go, random

A few years ago I wrote a simple "module" (https://github.com/parasit/rpgforge) to simulate dice rolls and "translate" human readable dice throw definiton to throws loops. Like "3d6" as 3 times roll six sides dice, etc.

I used it in my tools to support my hobby (pen & paper RPG). The code is simple, but so useful that I haven't really touched it for the last 4 years. However recently I needed another tool, imported my library and found the results very strange. Randomness seems to occur, but the results are returned as series of the same digits. I have no idea what's going on, and the only thing that has changed since the last time is golang from 1.18 to 1.19.

P.S. 1.19 is on win11, 1.18 is on second machine with ubuntu

Sample code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "time"

    forge "github.com/parasit/rpgforge"
)

func main() {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UTC().UnixNano())
    for x := 0; x < 10; x++ {
        fmt.Println(forge.ThrowDices("10d10"))
    }
}
```

Expected result (on old 1.18):

```
❯ go run ./main.go
{[6 6 2 6 7 7 10 3 4 3] 0}
{[1 7 7 8 6 1 3 3 6 3] 0}
{[7 4 5 1 3 9 6 7 1 1] 0}
{[1 1 7 2 10 4 5 6 10 7] 0}
{[2 10 10 1 10 3 9 10 3 6] 0}
{[2 8 1 3 1 3 5 4 6 2] 0}
{[3 9 4 5 9 2 4 7 6 6] 0}
{[3 5 7 1 6 4 8 10 9 2] 0}
{[3 6 4 8 1 7 8 10 4 1] 0}
{[2 9 2 8 9 8 5 6 7 2] 0}
```

But on 1.19 i got something like this:

```
{[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1] 0}
{[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1] 0}
{[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1] 0}
{[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1] 0}
{[8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8] 0}
{[8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8] 0}
{[8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8] 0}
{[8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8] 0}
{[8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 3] 0}
{[3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3] 0}
```

What happened in 1.19 ???

EDIT:
Mike had right, removing "initialize" from all rolls solve the problem. But requires add it "manually" to beginning of code.

Comment: It looks to me like you're reseeding the RNG at every call to Throw().  I don't know why that would have worked in 1.18 though.

Comment: @aMike You were right, removing "initialize" from each roll solved the problem. Looks like my computer is too fast :)

Answer (score 2):

You don't seem to need excessive speed, so I'd sidestep the issue by using a [cryptographically secure random number generator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32350135/589259). The [crypto/rand library](https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/rand)  uses the systems' random number generator, which is seeded by a lot better entropy than just a date.

Better randoms, less speed seems like a very reasonable tradeoff.